# SCSS How to create style on the fly

Tags: css, sass

I often use styles like next ones:

```
...
v-slot-padding-top4 {
    padding-top: 4px;
}

v-slot-padding-top16 {
    padding-top: 8px;
}
...
```

I can created many styles in cycle, but this way gives me many created styles that **I'll never use**.

Is there any way in scss to created styles on the fly? Or prepared something like function and call it from html attribute like class?

Answer (score 0):

SCSS (Sass) is a preprocessor scripting language. It will be converted to CSS. You cannot dynamically create styles on the fly (runtime).

But you can use Sass features like [@for](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for). To create all your classes in range you need.

**your.scss**:

```
@for $i from 1 through 16 {
  .v-slot-padding-top#{$i} {
    padding-top: #{$i}px
  }
}
```

Result in CSS:

```css
.v-slot-padding-top1 {
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.v-slot-padding-top2 {
  padding-top: 2px;
}

.v-slot-padding-top3 {
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.v-slot-padding-top4 {
  padding-top: 4px;
}

/* etc */
```

Comment: How bootstrap's spacing works? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/
It contains prepared file with all styles?

Comment: Yes it's the same. Loop through a range to prepare all classes. Take a look to the Bootstrap [source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/mixins/_grid.scss). This is a great feature of Sass to don't repeat styles. You write less. Finally it compiles to CSS. ... In CSS you could also use [custom variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) if you want more dynamic values.

Comment: In my case I would not like to create styles that I'll never use (styles top-3, top-5, top-7, top-8 and so on).

Comment: You could define an array with all values you need and iterate through it by [@each](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each). Like `[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]`. Or create it with a quadratic formula.